# Plain .tar.gz binary distribution of LIbreOffice?

Tags: centos, installer, libreoffice

Is there a place where I get recent (~3.4) LibreOffice binaries for Linux? I'm not looking for .debs or .rpms, just a plain archive I can extract in my home directory and run from there.

Since one of the computers I want this for is running a pretty old Linux (Scientific Linux 4, like CentOS 4), it would be great if it comes with all neccessary dependencies (recent gtk etc.) and would be compiled against an old glibc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can just download and extract the x86 rpms from http://www.libreoffice.org/download/ .

1. Get LibO_3.4.1_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US.tar.gz and extract it.
2. Go to LibO_3.4.1rc3_Linux_x86_install-rpm_en-US/RPMS
3. Extract all rpms:

   `for file in *.rpm; do rpm2cpio $file | cpio -idmv; done`
4. Go to `opt/libreoffice3.4/` and execute `program/soffice`. Voila!

It seems to run fine, opens my files, prints etc., although I don't have the exact versions stated as depencencies. Advanced stuff (java) might be broken, i haven't tested that, but it seems good enough.

Comment: Yes that's an option, but it's not guaranteed to work all the time, as you need dependencies, etc... Fortunately you had them, glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hidden...

http://www.libreoffice.org/download/

Go down, and expand **Download the source code to build your own installer**, at the bottom of that, expand **3.4.2.2** and you can download the `tar.bz2` packages there.

It is the source but you should be able to compile it pretty easily.

There's information [available here](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-involved/developers/) for compiling the source and running it.

Comment: Sorry, that just contains a lot of utility files to build LibO (branding, scripts, ...). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, you updated the question while I was commenting. I was hoping to avoid compiling everything myself. In that case, it would be easier to just do my office stuff on my notebook...

Comment: You're prettymuch going to have to compile it yourself unless you use a `.deb` or `.rpm`. The code has to compile for your distro of linux.

Comment: For what it's worth, following the instructions on the developer page i linked will get you the dependencies you need to compile it pretty fast.